# tbloader vs SPARQL INSERT - Why different behaviour with named graphs?

Tags: sparql, jena, tdb, arq, named-graphs

There is a strange behaviour in the connection of the commandline tools of ARQ, TDB and Named Graphs. If importing data via tdbloader in a named graph it can not be queried via GRAPH clause in a SPARQL SELECT query. However, this query is possible when inserting the data in the same graph with SPARQL INSERT.

I have following assembler description file *tdb.ttl*:

```
@prefix rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf:    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix ja:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .


[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .
tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
tdb:GraphTDB    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

[] rdf:type         tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "DB" ;
.
```

There is a dataset in the file *data.ttl*:

```
<a> <b> <c>.
```

Now, I am inserting this data with tdbloader and secondly another triple with SPARQL INSERT, both in the named graph *data*:

```
tdbloader --desc tdb.ttl --graph data data.ttl
update --desc tdb.ttl "INSERT DATA {GRAPH <data> {<d> <e> <f>.}}"
```

Now, the data can be queried with SPARQL via:

```
$arq --desc tdb.ttl "SELECT *  WHERE{ GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o.}}"
----------------------------
| s   | p   | o   | g      |
============================
| <a> | <b> | <c> | <data> |
| <d> | <e> | <f> | <data> |
----------------------------
```

Everything seems perfect. But now I want to query only this specifc named graph *data*:

```
$ arq --desc tdb.ttl "SELECT *  WHERE{ GRAPH <data> {?s ?p ?o.}}"
-------------------
| s   | p   | o   |
===================
| <d> | <e> | <f> |
-------------------
```

Why is the data imported from tdbloader missing? What is wrong with this query? How can I get results back from both imports?

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but _thank you_ for a very well thought out question with a minimal working example that we can use to reproduce the problem!

Comment: For three more interesting results, see http://pastebin.com/3cT4fagi.  In short, `SELECT * WHERE { values ?g { <data> } graph ?g { ?s ?p ?o }}` returns only **one** value, but `SELECT * WHERE { values ?s { <a> <d> } graph ?g { ?s ?p ?o }}` returns **two**, and `SELECT * WHERE { values ?g { <data> UNDEF } graph ?g { ?s ?p ?o }}` returns **three** (there's a duplicate result).

Comment: Interestingly, if you use an absolute URI instead of a relative one, as I've shown in http://pastebin.com/ViWmNmWT, you'll get the kinds of results that you want.

Comment: I wonder if what's going on here is that the relative URIs in `tdbloader --desc tdb.ttl --graph data data.ttl` and  `update --desc tdb.ttl "INSERT DATA {GRAPH <data> {<d> <e> <f>.}}"` are getting resolved differently so that you're ending up with two different URIs that happen to be printed in the same way in these results.

Comment: Yes - thank you for a complete, minimal example.  I have spent more time answering this that I might otherwise have done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this query:

```
PREFIX : <data>
SELECT * { { ?s ?p ?o } UNION { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } } }
```

and the output is

```
----------------------------
| s   | p   | o   | g      |
============================
| <a> | <b> | <c> | <data> |
| <d> | <e> | <f> | :      |
----------------------------
```

or try:

```
 tdbquery --loc DB --file Q.rq -results srj
```

to get the results in a different form.

The text output is makign things look nice but two different things end up as `<data>`.

What you are seeing is that

```
tdbloader --desc tdb.ttl --graph data data.ttl
```

used `data` exactly as is to name the graph.  But

```
INSERT DATA {GRAPH <data> {<d> <e> <f>.}}
```

does a full SPARQL parse, and resolves  against the base URI, probably looking like `file://*currentdirectory*`.

When printing in text, URIs get abbreviated, including using the base.  So both the original `data` (from tdbloader) and `file:///path/data` appear as `<data>`.

```
PREFIX : <data>
```

gives the text output a different way to write it as `:`.

Finally try:

```
BASE <http://example/>
SELECT * { { ?s ?p ?o } UNION { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } } }
```

which sets the base URI to something no where near your data URIs so switching off nice formatting by base URI:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| s                        | p                        | o                        | g                           |
================================================================================================================
| <file:///home/afs/tmp/a> | <file:///home/afs/tmp/b> | <file:///home/afs/tmp/c> | <data>                      |
| <file:///home/afs/tmp/d> | <file:///home/afs/tmp/e> | <file:///home/afs/tmp/f> | <file:///home/afs/tmp/data> |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of this issue. Then I will use absolute URIs. Then, the UNION is not necessary.